# MYSQL error in adding row number

Tags: mysql

I have this sql

```
SET @rank:=0;

SELECT u.userid, a.referreid, c.avatar,c.avatarapproved, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank , SUM( a.points ) as sum_points FROM 
ade39_alpha_userpoints_details AS a, ade39_alpha_userpoints as u ,ade39_findme as c 
WHERE (u.referreid = a.referreid) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= a.insert_date 
AND (u.userid= c.user_id) AND (u.userid >0) 
GROUP BY a.referreid
 ORDER BY sum_points DESC LIMIT 200
```

it was working correct but after adding "rank" for row number it is "not working" =>> the output is empty. When i remove "@rank:=@rank+1 AS rank " it is working

Comment: the output is empty. When i remove "@rank:=@rank+1 AS rank " it is working

Comment: I have tried this


SELECT u.userid, a.referreid, c.avatar,c.avatarapproved, SUM( a.points ) as sum_points ,


(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( SUM( a.points ) ORDER BY SUM( a.points ) DESC ) 
FROM ade39_alpha_userpoints_details 
) AS rank

FROM 
ade39_alpha_userpoints_details AS a, ade39_alpha_userpoints as u ,ade39_findme as c 


WHERE (u.referreid = a.referreid) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= a.insert_date 
AND (u.userid= c.user_id) AND (u.userid >0) 
GROUP BY a.referreid
 ORDER BY sum_points DESC LIMIT 200

but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should group by all the columns which are not used with aggregate functions in the field list of a select. MySQL is able to handle it quite well, but it probably cannot deal with the variable. (Read more under the [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) section of the manual.)

Try to embed your original query in a subquery (but be careful with the ordering).

```
SET @rank:=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, * FROM (
  SELECT u.userid, a.referreid, c.avatar,c.avatarapproved, SUM( a.points ) AS sum_points
  FROM ade39_alpha_userpoints_details AS a,
       ade39_alpha_userpoints AS u,
       ade39_findme AS c 
  WHERE (u.referreid = a.referreid) AND
    DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= a.insert_date AND
    (u.userid= c.user_id) AND (u.userid >0) 
  GROUP BY a.referreid) T
ORDER BY sum_points DESC LIMIT 200
```